# Filtering multiple values out of a single line of text

Tags: powershell

Here is an example line of text:

```
@{id=DS1622894; type=dataSourceAlert; internalId=LMD119923; startEpoch=1685861681; endEpoch=0; acked=True; ackedEpoch=1685978483; ackedBy=username; ackComment=.; rule=Warning; ruleId=1; chain=NoEscalation; chainId=2; subChainId=0; nextRecipient=0; receivedList=; severity=2; cleared=False; sdted=False; SDT=; alertValue=86.6657; threshold=>= 85 95; clearValue=; monitorObjectId=1257; monitorObjectType=device; monitorObjectName=hq-esx-mdf-2 - 10.1.30.22; monitorObjectGroups=    ; resourceId=7262; resourceTemplateId=94; resourceTemplateType=DS; resourceTemplateName=VMware Datastore Capacity; instanceId=207544; instanceName=VMware_ESXi_DatastoreCapacity-Marketing; instanceDescription=35.0 TB  VMFS; dataPointName=PercentUsed; dataPointId=648; detailMessage=; customColumns=; enableAnomalyAlertSuppression=; enableAnomalyAlertGeneration=}
```

I want to pull out just id, startepoch, and ackedepoch.
My text file is full of lines just like the one above and I want to repeat this process for each line.

```
$parsedbody | Set-Content "C:\windows\temp\parsedbody.txt"
$pattern1 = "id"
$pattern2 = "startepoch"
$pattern3 = "ackedepoch"
Get-Content "C:\windows\temp\parsedbody.txt" | Where-Object {$_ -match "$pattern1|$pattern2|$pattern3"} | Set-Content "C:\windows\temp\parsedbody1.txt"
```

Disclaimer: huge noob. Really appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have in `parsedbody.txt` is a string representation of a `PSCustomObject`, you can use the [`Parser` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.parser?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) to parse it back into an object and from there filter the information you need:

```bash
$out = [ordered]@{}
$body = Get-Content 'C:\windows\temp\parsedbody.txt' -Raw
$ast = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($body, [ref] $null, [ref] $null)
$ast[0].EndBlock.Statements.PipelineElements.Expression.KeyValuePairs |
    Where-Object Item1 -In id, startepoch, ackedepoch |
    ForEach-Object { $out[$_.Item1] = $_.Item2.ToString() }

[pscustomobject] $out
```

Using the data in the question this would return:

```
id        startEpoch ackedEpoch
--        ---------- ----------
DS1622894 1685861681 1685978483
```

Clearly this is the incorrect way to export objects, there are built-in cmdlets that handle the conversion of objects into structured data, i.e.: `Export-Csv`, `ConvertTo-Json`, etc..

For instance, if you were using `Export-Csv` to export this object then the process would be as simple as:

```
# Export
$parsedbody | Export-Csv C:\windows\temp\parsedbody.Csv
# Import and select the desired properties
Import-Csv C:\windows\temp\parsedbody.Csv |
    Select-Object id, startepoch, ackedepoch
```

Comment: good point, thanks @mklement0 for the keys its not needed if casted to `pscustomobject`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am glad you showed me a better way to do this :)

Comment: @JacobKing glad this was helpful :)